# Waterline - Where with sum of fields

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sails.js, waterline

I've got the following model `Test`

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        a: {
            type: 'number'
        },
        b: {
            type: 'number'
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to build a query that allows me to put sum of fields `a` and `b` in where statement.

SQL equavilent:

```
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE a + b = myValue
```

I read in sails doc's about [Criteria modifiers](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/query-language#?criteria-modifiers) but there is no word about that.

Is there any clever way to do that? Of course I can use [native query](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/datastores/send-native-query) but I would like to avoid that because I must use the sum along with other modifiers. The reason is I'm generating dynamic queries from separate files and with native queries I will have to also handle already defined functionality like or, and, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround. Maybe it will be useful to someone.
It is not stricte sails/node solution, but database one, however, it fits my case perfectly.

From MySQL 5.7 there is something like [generated columns](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-generated-columns/).

> Columns are generated because the data in these columns are computed based on predefined expressions.

All I had to do was add an extra, auto generated column to my `Test` model:

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        a: {
            type: 'number',
            columnType: 'int'
        },
        b: {
            type: 'number',
            columnType: 'int'
        },
        c: {
            type: 'number',
            columnType: 'int GENERATED ALWAYS AS(a + b) VIRTUAL'
        }
    }
}
```

Now I'm able to do such query:

```
const result = await Test.find({ c: 2 })
```

...and I get the correct result. Waterline treats my column like any other, database does everything instead of me.

Of course I can mix it with other modifiers with no problems.

I haven't seen any complications so far.